# CALayer shadowColor not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, shadow

So I set the shadow of a layer of an UIView correctly the first time (it shows perfectly fine) but when I try to change the color (nothing else, just the `layer.shadowColor`) it won't update in the view. It still shows the original color. I already tried `layer setNeedsDisplay` without any luck.

```
self.profileIconShadow.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileIcon.frame.size.height / 2;
self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowRadius = self.profileIcon.frame.size.width * .025;
self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
```

[image]

```
// if ([entry[@"isInactive"] boolValue]) { // Original
if (true) { // Overrode temporarily to test it out
    self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    [self.profileIconShadow.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The shadow get set correctly the first time as needed. But then I try changing the color it still stays black instead of turning red.

[image]

This is how it should look.

Edit #2: I have noticed that if I comment out the black color when I first make the shadow, it will change to red later on. Can I not change `shadowColor` multiple times?

Comment: Tried it and working perfectly to me.. Are you sure your not assigning color to `self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowColor` somewhere else?

Comment: @0yeoj I only have the code where I set it black at first and then where it should change to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code last night, i even made an animation of on and off switch out of your code before i went to sleep.. haha..

The question: `Can I not change shadowColor multiple times?`, of course you can.. ;)

The only potential reason why your layer is not updating is maybe it is not executed in the main thread, to make sure try this:

```
if ([entry[@"isInactive"] boolValue]) 
{ // Original
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 

        self.profileIconShadow.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

        [self.profileIconShadow.layer setNeedsDisplay];

    }
}
```